# How do I make a button appear just for a limited time?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uibutton

I have a UIButton: `@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) { }`. What I want is to just display it for two days after the user downloads the app, then I want it to disappear.

I created a (Countdown) timer:

```
var timer:Timer?
var time = 172800 //2Days
```

Then I created this function:

```
@objc func passedTime(){
    time -= 1

    if time <= 0 {
        timer!.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

In my viewDidLoad:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(passedTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

I obviously want the time to go on even if the user closes the app as well.

Comment: Don't put tags in the title. Don't use "quote" markup for text you are not quoting. The edits were made for a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a timer while the app is closed. This is what you need to do when the user opens the app:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button:UIButton!

if let stored = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"storedDate") as? Date
  , Date() > stored {

       self.button.isHidden = true
}
else {
     let today = Date()
     let after2Days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 2, to: today)
     // save
     UserDefaults.standard.set(after2Days,forKey:"storedDate")
}
```

Comment: And how do I hide the button?

Comment: Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'isHidden'

Comment: I didn't say that, I tried to do that but it doesn't work... :(

Comment: Please note that while this is the right solution to start, depending on the needs of the app, this may not be enough. A timer may still be required, in addition to this answer, to ensure the button actually goes away exactly 2 days after the first run of the app.

Comment: @rmaddy how should I do?

Comment: @rmaddy i don't think a user may still be opening an app for 2 days , plus if it's the case then the timer should be initiated from the date the app is opened and continuously compared to stored data if exists , a good approach also  is to store that date in server so to take care if user changes device date in case if hiding the button deserves that extra effort

Comment: I'm talking about the more likely case of the user opening the app just a few minutes before the 2 days are up. The app is sitting in the foreground or it gets suspended for several hours and the user returns to the foreground. Now the 2 days has passed but since the app wasn't restarted, the button is still in view. It largely depends on where the code in this answer is run and how close to the 2 days the button actually needs to be removed. I'm just giving the OP things to consider.

Comment: @chestres if you need to handle that case just copy the code in answer and put it in the timer function for sure outlet is away from it

Comment: I tested it with minutes and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @rmaddy what would you do with the timer?